# Program type already present: com.mapbox.android.core.location.GoogleLocationEngine

Tags: android, gradle, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm trying to use Mapbox together with google play services location.

Everything worked fine until I added `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'` to be able to request location updates when app in background.

Gradle builds fine but when compiling the project I get the following error:

```
....
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: com.mapbox.android.core.location.GoogleLocationEngine$1$2
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:116)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:74)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:59)
... 57 more
```

I had a similar problem before and I was able to exclude the library causing the issue. However, with Mapbox I can't figure out how to resolve this conflict.

What I tried:

```
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.8.0'){
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms", module: "play-services-location"
} // Probably will have no effect as this module doesn't seem to be a dependency of Mapbox
```

OR

```
implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'){
    force = true
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Trying the version 7.0.0 beta2 of Mapbox seems to solve the issue, but I would like to avoid using a beta version in prod, so if there is any way I can make the current version of Mapbox with `google play services location` it will be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add android location services :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

At the end of build.gradle(app level) after dependencies close section add this line :

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Like this :

```
    dependencies {
       ...
       implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: This is already the case. The problem is the conflict with mapbox

Comment: As i see in downloaded telemetry v 3.5.6 that used by mapbox v 6.8.0 it's using gms location service 11.0.4

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-android/releases/tag/telem-3.5.6

Comment: Change gms version to 11.0.4 if it has your requirements , i think it will solve

Comment: This didn't work as the version 11.0.4 doesn't include all the features I need. Do you know how to exclude `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location` from mapbox ? So mapbox only uses the one I import separetly ?